# Как покрасить все колонны таблицы вертикально?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При клике на кнопку надо покрасить все колонны таблицы вертикально, в моем коде окрашивается  только первая колонна. (Когда написано val++, окрашивание идет горизонтально,)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let val = 0;
  $("#nerkel").click(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $("td").eq(val).css("background", "lime")
      val += 10
    }, 30)
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>

<button class="btn btn-warning" id="nerkel">Красить</button>
```

Comment: Кто-то не умеет циклы...

Comment: кто-то не знает что такое setInterval....

Comment: а `clearInterval` где?

Comment: о! кажется, я вопрос понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nerkel").click(function() {
    let row = 0, cell = 0;
   
    function colorCell() {
      $("tr").eq(row++).find("td").eq(cell).css("background", "lime");
      if (row == $("tr").length) {
        row = 0;
        cell++;
      }
      if (cell < $("tr:last td").length)
        setTimeout(colorCell, 30);
    }
    colorCell();
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
  <tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>
</table>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="nerkel">Красить</button>
```

Comment: спасибо большое))